# How to change build-in attribute of image in Python?

Tags: python, windows, image, python-imaging-library

you know that once you open an image in Windows and open attribute window you would find detailed information in that sub-window ,like below 
[image]

and you will find pixel infos and camera infos and things like that or even your latitude location!
[image]

There is one line called Memo:
[image]

Where you can randomly add some postscript according to that name

But, how to manually change or add infos into the attribute of image?

Python PIL can only acquire size infos or mode infos , i dont find any API to adjust such kind of info

Comment: maybe [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) or [python wrapper on exiftool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/)

Comment: ``pyexiv2`` can do this.